# print a value from mutiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to print a value from mutiple arrays in PHP?

e.g. Here is the structure I have and I want to print `filepath` from these arryas, here it's clear that we have two arrays but in my case it's dynamic.  How can I print `filepath` from unknown number of arrays?

```
[field_pic] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 29
                [uid] => 1
                [filename] => 011.jpg
                [filepath] => sites/default/files/011.jpg
                [filemime] => image/jpeg
                [filesize] => 154608
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1349463183
                [list] => 1
                [data] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 31
                [uid] => 1
                [filename] => 019.jpg
                [filepath] => sites/default/files/019.jpg
                [filemime] => image/jpeg
                [filesize] => 158635
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1349463188
                [list] => 1
                [data] => 
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
for($i = count($field_pic) -1 ; $i >= 0 ; $i-- ){ //You have to substract 1 to the array length because it's of bound
    echo "filepath=" . $field_pic[$i]['filepath'];
}
```

Example :

```
$arr = array(1,2,3)
```

`Count($arr) = 3;`
but `$array[3] = undefined;

Comment: Really Thanks, Solved my problem and also learned a new thing.

Comment: Sorry but if creates a blank value at first and then the `filepath` How can I fix this?

Comment: Feels like reverse engineering

Answer (score 2):

Outputs each file path on it's own line

```
foreach( $field_pics as $field_pic )
{
    echo $field_pic['filepath'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I tried your snippet and nothing happened, I think I'm doing something wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($field_pic as $pic)
   var_dump($pic["filepath"]);
```

do you want it like this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your 2D array is called `$main` the following should achieve your goal:

```
#create an array to store the filenames
$filenames_array = array();

# this will loop through the first array
foreach($main as $subarray)
{
     # append the filename to the end of the array you created to store these names
     $filenames_array[] = $subarray['filename'];
}

var_dump($filenames_array);
```

That should solve this problem.

P.S. Is this your homework?

Answer (score 0):

Really Thanks to everyone, This is how I fixed it:

```
for($i = count($node->field_pic) ; $i >= 0 ; $i-- ){
    echo $node->field_pic[$i]['filepath'];
}
```